# Twitter Bootstrap Wizard Plugin Summary

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using the [Twitter Bootstrap Wizard Plugin](http://vinceg.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/) and have an 8 step form set up. On steps 1-7, the user enters information. On step 8 I would like to see all of the information that was entered on steps 1-7 as a summary page with. How can I create this? If it matters at all, my main code is in CF9.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways to go about it. One easy way using jQuery would be to

do on event `$('#LastPageTab').click(function{});`

`.empty()` the summary div, then `.clone()` and `.appendTo()` all of the other page divs into the final container tab contents.

This is just by hand, but this should get you started since I don't know how the event is going to be triggered. just replace the call with whatever event you can have fired when the summary tab is navigated to.

```
$('#LastPageTabId').click(function{
    $('#SummaryContentId').empty();
    $('#Page1ContentId').clone().appendTo('#SummaryContentId');
    // or iterate through pages, either way, appendTo for all pages needed
});
```